# How to get pid from binary which the run via getRuntime().exec

Tags: android

How to get pid from binary which the run via getRuntime().exec.
I want to get pid from `/data/data/com.tes.tes/binary`

My code to run the service is:

```
MyExecShell("/data/data/com.tes.tes/binary");

public void MyExecShell(String cmd) {
    Process p = null;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

If I run command `ps | grep binary` I get result:

```
app_96    12468 1     1176   680   c0194d70 0007efb4 S /data/data/com.tes.tes/binary
```

I want to get the pid, how to do it? I have tried with this:

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> list = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (list != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
                Log.d("DLOG", list.get(i).toString() + "\n");
                if ("/data/data/com.tes.tes/binary"
                        .matches(list.get(i).toString())) {
                    int pid = android.os.Process.getUidForName("/data/data/com.tes.tes/binary");
                    Log.d("DLOG","PID: "+pid);
                }
            }
        }
```

But not success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the running process is not an app context.
You can try to fetch the pid by standard Linux methods:

```
private int getPid() {
    int pid = -1;
    Process p = null;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps");
        p.waitFor();
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String s;
        while ((s=r.readLine())!= null) {
            if (s.contains("/data/data/com.tes.tes/binary")) {
                // TODO get pid from ps output
                // like " | awk '{ pring $2 }'
                // pid = something;
            }
        }
        r.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return pid;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply,
By the way wether all android device have binary 'ps' ? If yes I will use your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: As far as I know: yes.

Comment: Okay thanks. Solved my problem with your answer to use set number pid via runtime exec.